# Regex JavaScript multiline group matching returns just part of expected result in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-group

I want match group from `--[[` to `--]]` + one line after that with `contents.match(new RegExp(/--\[\[\s([^]*?)\s--\]\]\s(.*)/, 'g'));`

Why testing this regex in JS mode on https://regex101.com/r/7yjQCS/2 works, but in node.js I get match untill `--]]`?

-

result:

`--[[
 * a
 * b
 * c
--]]`

-

expected:

`--[[
 * a
 * b
 * c
--]]
function name(x, y) {`

-

code:

`var contents = "--[[\n * a\n * b\n * c\n--]]\nfunction name(x, y) {\n ...\n}\n\n--[[\n * a\n * b\n * c\n--]]\nfunction name(x, y) {\n ...\n}";
var inputs = contents.match(new RegExp(/--\[\[\s([^]*?)\s--\]\]\s(.*)/, 'g'));`

Comment: I don´t know in which node version you are, but, running your code exactly as you´ve written gave me the desired expected output. Tested on Node.js v6.9.2

Comment: I get `[
  "--[[\n * a\n * b\n * c\n--]]\nfunction name(x, y) {",
  "--[[\n * a\n * b\n * c\n--]]\nfunction name(x, y) {"
]` - what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^]` is an error in regex land.

The reason is it is undefined.
A negative class must have something to *negate*, otherwise it has no meaning.

If JS doesn't throw an error, the behavior is unpredictable.

What you should use instead is `[\S\s]` because this matches any character.

Also, the reason that it is not matching the last line in your production JS
is you only allow a single whitespace `\s` before the line.
Since the last line is optional, the whitespace matches the `CR` of a `CRLF`
pair ( in MS OS ).

To fix that, make it open ended `\s+`.
Also, the first two `\s` are not needed, since you match *any char* between `[[ ]]`

The final regex would now look like this https://regex101.com/r/7yjQCS/4
that works on any platform.

`--\[\[([\S\s]*?)--\]\]\s+(.*)`